# Unable to get the values entering in the tex box its showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i'm not getting the first user and lastname. Please update me
 its form1:its showing the text based `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`  to the form

```
<html>
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">

 </head>
 <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
       <h3>SessionStateData</h3>
       <table>
       <tr>
          <td>FirstName:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtfName" runat="server"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>SecondName:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtlName" runat="server"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> 
              <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind the form on button submit is:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["FirstName"] = txtfName;
        Session["SecondName"] = txtlName;
        Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
    }
```

Form 2:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">

    </head>
    <body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <h3>Default2.aspx</h3>
   <table>
      <tr>
     <td colspan="2">Welcome <b><asp:Label ID="lblString" runat="server"/></b></td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Your FirstName: </td><td><b><asp:Label ID="lblfName" runat="server"/></b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Your SecondName </td><td><b><asp:Label ID="lbllName" runat="server"/></b></td>
     </tr>
        <tr><td></td><td> </td></tr>
    </table>
   </div>
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and the code behind is :

```
       if(!IsPostBack)
          {
     if (Session["FirstName"] != null && Session["SecondName"] != null)
     {
      lblString.Text = Session["FirstName"]+" " + Session["LastName"];
        lblfName.Text = Session["FirstName"].ToString();
         lbllName.Text = Session["LastName"].ToString();

  }
      else
    {

  Session["FirstName"] = "raj";
  Session["SecondName"] = "shikre";
 lblString.Text = "Welcome " + Session["FirstName"] + Session["SecondName"];
   } 
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Text` property of the `TextBox` controls to get the Value.

Replace This:

```
    Session["FirstName"] = txtfName;
    Session["SecondName"] = txtlName;
```

With This:

```
    Session["FirstName"] = txtfName.Text;
    Session["SecondName"] = txtlName.Text;
```

**Complete Code:**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["FirstName"] = txtfName.Text;
    Session["SecondName"] = txtlName.Text;
    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
}
```